# Can the editor state be sync'd with the button state for basic styles

Tags: ckeditor

When deleting a text block with a basic style applied, the editor remains in the active state (bold, for example) while the button for that style is deactivated.  Typing a character will reactivate the button.

I have verified that this is occurs on the CKEditor demo as well, so it shouldn't be related to any changes in our installation.

Steps to reproduce:

```
Use standard CKEditor: http://ckeditor.com/demo#standard
Select all and delete existing contents
Type 'Hello, World'
Select 'World'
Click 'Bold' button (or Ctrl+B)
Move cursor to end of content
Remove via backspace until bold content is removed
```

This results in the button displaying as inactive (default state), but typing any content will enter the text in bold and reactivate the button.

I've reproduced this (with slightly different rules regarding blank content and trailing spaces) on Chrome, Firefox, and IE10.

Is there a way to pull the state at which new content would be entered into the editor and use that to update the button state so that a user can see what their entered content will input as?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this TC very well:

- delete entire bold, bold button is inactive,
- start typing again,
- bold is applied :|

It occurs on Webkit (Chrome and Safari) because of a very ugly behaviour of Webkit's contenteditable behaviour.

This is reported here:

- http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/9998 - CKEditor (ticket grouping all Webkit's backspace handling bugs)
- https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=226941 - Chromium
- https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=114791 - Webkit

Unfortunately neither Chromium's nor Webkit's developers replied and perhaps as most of the contenteditable bugs, this one won't be fixed soon (there are critical issues that haven't been fixed for years). So perhaps, in the near future we'll fix this on the CKEditor's side by overriding entire backspace logic with our own. Then such issues should not exist.

PS. Regarding the rest of the browsers I know that there are small inconsistencies, but you won't be able to fix them. Like for the Webkit's bug, to fix these cases we need to create custom backspace handling.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up on this.  It looks like some of the other issues on our punch list is handled in that ticket grouping as well.